# Why not use the builtin C# event keyword instead of using another framework

Tags: c#, events

I have read quite a lot about Domain Driven Design (DDD) the last couple of months, which makes use of the concept called *Domain Events*. All examples I have seen so far use either a framework like [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) or [FluentEvents](https://github.com/luca-esse/FluentEvents), or they use another self-made implementation.

Today I was discussing MediatR with my colleague and he asked why I didn't just use the C# buildin `event` keyword, which seems to do the same. After googling for a couple of hours I found a lot more examples, all without the `event` keyword, but no explanation why they don't use it.

Can anyone give me one or more good reasons why other methods are preferred over the builtin `event` keyword.

Comment: I have not used those libraries but one of the general reasons is to decouple event publishers and consumers. Events in C# require a strong reference from the publisher to the consumer, which couples the lifetime of consumers to publishers. If you want either of those to be short lived you have to manage maintaining the event subscription some how. It can also be convenient in some architectures to allow anyone to raise an event, particularly user interfaces where the "event" might be "show this dialog to the user".

Comment: A third reason would be that C# events are not first-class in sense that I cannot treat events as objects and pass them to methods and compose them. F# does this, for example, with its own IEvent interface.